# undefined variable in VUE component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar

For some reason I am able to access `this.id` in my methods section but not in my data section. I have read some posts on the nuances of the `this` keyword but could not figure our why `this.id` is `undefined` in my data section. Here is the code:

calendar.vue (the important parts):

```
export default {
   name: 'calendar',
   data() {
      return {    
         eventSources: [
         // your event source
            {
               url: 'http://localhost:3000/getAppointments',
               type: 'GET',
               data: {     
                   id: this.id //this.id is undefined
               },
            }
         ],
         selected: {},
         val: [],
         id: this.$store.getters.user,
      };
   },
   methods: {
      getApts: function(){
         this.$http.get('http://localhost:3000/getAppointments?id='+this.id)
      //here this.id is defined 
      }
   }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the data function is called to initialize your Vue, inside the data function, `this` will be bound to the Vue. In the code above, there is no `id` property of the Vue because Vue is in the process of attaching all the data properties you have defined. That is why `this.id` is `undefined`.

I would suggest you just use

```
  data() {
    return {    
      eventSources: [
        // your event source
        {
          url: 'http://localhost:3000/getAppointments',
          type: 'GET',
          data: {     
            id: this.$store.getters.user
          },
        }
      ],
      selected: {},
      val: [],
      id: this.$store.getters.user,
    };
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the value you want into a variable and use that.  This way you don't need to duplicate your code where you get the id from the store.

```
  data() {
    const id = this.$store.getters.user;
    return {    
      eventSources: [
        // your event source
        {
          url: 'http://localhost:3000/getAppointments',
          type: 'GET',
          data: {     
            id,
          },
        }
      ],
      selected: {},
      val: [],
      id,
    };
  },
```